# Failed create table

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I fail all the CREATE TABLE; and INSERT statements with the error `no such a table`.

This does not happen with Android 2.3. Instead it with a 3.2. Why is that? Error creating the database?

My class example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String queryTest="create table TEST_TABLE(ID integer,T_MESSAGE text)";
    databaseHelper.executeQuery(queryTest);
    queryTest="INSERT INTO TEST_TABLE (ID,T_MESSAGE) VALUES (1,'1');";
    databaseHelper.executeQuery(queryTest);

}
```

}

My database:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DATABASE_NAME = "pro.db";
private static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/it.sysman.mobile.contactpro/databases/";



private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION = 2;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqlDB) {
    try {



    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private SQLiteDatabase openDataBase(int flag) {

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {

        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Environment.getDataDirectory();
        Environment.getRootDirectory();
        Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        checkDB = getWritableDatabase();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return checkDB;
}


public String executeQuery(String query) {

    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = null;
    Cursor data = null;
    try {
        sqlDB = openDataBase(SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        data = sqlDB.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (data.getCount() == 0)
            return null;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (data != null)
            data.close();
        if (sqlDB != null)
            sqlDB.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you create the database and copy it to the assets folder?

Answer (score -1):

there are a number of remarks here:

### One:

If you insist on creating the database outside of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. then use `execQuery()` and not `rawQuery()`. I don't know if this will solve the issue, but this is the method you should use for sql queries that does not return results.

### Two:

It is prefered to do the creation of your database inside the `SQLiteOpenHelper` and let it manage the creation and updating of your database.

see [this blog post](http://blog.kdehairy.com/2012/08/19/using-a-preloaded-sqlite-database-with-sqliteopenhelper/) if you want to use a pre-loaded database with your application.

Comment: If I insert ExecQuery returns me this error:                                 The method execQuery(String, null) is undefined for the type SQLiteDatabase.                                                                        how can I fix it? How do I change my code to create my database inside the SQLiteOpenHelper? sorry and thanks

Comment: ok @Andrea_dev first read the blog post i referred to in my answer, and let me know if you find any difficulties. by the way, it's my blog, so feel free to reply here or there.

Comment: you're welcome. perhaps you could choose this answer as the right one ;-)